# how to convert a war file into project?

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex4.5

I h've a war file of a project which has written in flash builder 4.5 I just want to convert it into project.
I cannt use winzip e.t.c . I need a soultion from command prompt or any other method .
Any help appreciated. How to extract flex project from the war file?

I just need source code of the war file. N't  the .as files or .mxml file.

Comment: Yes you can unzip a .war file, altho the .war might not be associated with your winzip program. Right-click and choose open with, or open your winzip (or winrar etc) and open it from there

Answer (score 3):

Just unzip the WAR file and put the files you find in your project sources folder

Comment: but how to unpack on right click it does nt show any option of unzip or extract

Comment: @ricky just rename it from `yourfile.war` to `yourfile.zip` and then extract it

Answer (score 0):

war is simple archive, if it includes the sources, just unpack it and improt the files to your project